# How can we append multiple items to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to loop through multiple text files, and get the name of each file along with the headers of each file.  Basically, I'm trying to get the file name and the file schema, which will become a table in a database.  Here is the code that I am testing.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

results = pd.DataFrame([])
#results=[]
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\test\\*.txt")
number_of_lines = 2
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        head = [next(myfile) for x in range(2)]
        results.append(filename)
        results.append(head)
```

When I run that code, I end up with this error.

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

I want to end up with something like this, for the first three files.

File1:

```
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RICI 09302019.txt
IDRSSD  RCFDM708    RCFDM709    RCFDM710
    RE CNSTR LN RECD INVST:INDV IMPARMNT    RE CNSTR LN ALLW BAL: INDV IMPAIRMNT    RE CNSTR LN RECD INVST:COLL IMPARMNT
```

File2:

```
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RICI 09302020.txt
IDRSSD  RCFDM708    RCFDM709    RCFDM710
    RE CNSTR LN RECD INVST:INDV IMPARMNT    RE CNSTR LN ALLW BAL: INDV IMPAIRMNT    RE CNSTR LN RECD INVST:COLL IMPARMNT
```

File3:

```
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RICI 12312019.txt
IDRSSD  RCFDM708    RCFDM709    RCFDM710
    RE CNSTR LN RECD INVST:INDV IMPARMNT    RE CNSTR LN ALLW BAL: INDV IMPAIRMNT    RE CNSTR LN RECD INVST:COLL IMPARMNT
```

I have around 3,700 text files, so I really want to automate this process of logging file names and file schemas.  Here's the code that I tried.

Comment: You ask "How can we append multiple items to a list?", but the thing you want to append multiple items to *isn't a list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious if just adding the lines to a results list would be sufficient for your needs:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

# Use a list here rather than a dataframe
results=[]
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\test\\*.txt")
number_of_lines = 2
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        head = [next(myfile) for x in range(2)]
        results.append([filename, *head])

# You can build a dataframe from that list at the end if you desire
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns=['filename', 'head_1', 'head_2'])
```

Comment: Wow, I was so close and yet so far too. This is very close, but how can I put the 'results += head' in the next field over, like ColumnB in a CSV file, instead of under the next row? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - you were pretty close! Updated the answer to have one row per file, with three columns per row.

Comment: Side-note: On 3.5+, you can simplify repeated indexing when you want the whole `list` anyway, and it's both simpler and faster. Rather than `results.append([filename, head[0], head[1]])`, you just do: `results.append([filename, *head])`. I might even suggest removing the definition of `head`, and just importing `itertools` so you can do `results.append([filename, *itertools.islice(myfile, 2)])` and save repeated `next` calls and the temporary `list` (behavioral difference; a file with only one line will silently produce one item with `islice`; repeated `next` would raise `StopIteration`).

Comment: I like the improvement of `*head`, less clunky while still being pretty close to original code. Updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update Matthew, but it seems like something is off.  You are missing a quotation before head_2, and even when I add that in, I get this error.

ValueError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 7973 columns